# two probability questions (related to lower bounding error probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Recently, I ran into the following $2$ problems. Say you have a fair coin which you toss $n$ times. Now, here is my first question.

> I want to check whether the lower bound on the probability that you end up observing at least $\frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{n}$ many heads is a constant, i.e., whether $$p_1 = \Pr (X \geq \frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{n}) \geq \Omega(1)$$ (where $X$ is a random variable counting number of heads)

If we want to find a lower bound on observing at least $\frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{n} \cdot O(\sqrt{ln (\frac{1}{\delta})})$ many heads for some fraction $
\delta$, then it can be upper bounded by $O(\delta)$ i.e., $$p_2 = \Pr (X \geq \frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{O(n \cdot \ln{(\frac{1}{\delta})}}) \leq O(\delta)$$

Chernoff bounds only give an upper bound on $p_1$. I would like to know what is a good lower bound on $p_1$ and it would be great if you can share some more references which help in finding these kinds of lower bounds.

Also, on a related note, I would like to understand how does one find such opposite to concentration bounds in general. Let us say that I want to find a lower bound like the following - that in $n$ tosses of a fair coin, the number of heads observed is within a certain small range $[l,u]$ - how do you that.  Being a bit more concrete, say we ask the following.

> We know that the expected difference between number of heads and number of tails in $n$ tosses of a fair coin is proportional to $\sqrt{n}$. I would like to find an upper bound on  the probability that number of heads falls in some small interval of size $\sqrt{n}$ scaled down by a fraction, i.e., if $$p = \Pr(X \in (\frac{n}{2} - \delta \cdot \sqrt{n}, \frac{n}{2} + \delta \cdot \sqrt{n}))$$, then can i get a good upper bound on $p$ in terms of just $\delta$?

Please let me know how do you go about proving these opposite to concentration kind of results -- any reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One can calculate explicitly until CLT takes over.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Hi Andre, I am not sure I follow. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: If we prtend that we are dealing with a normal, we can look up (in a table of the standard normal) the relevant probability for fixed reasonable $\delta$. And we can give an estimate as an explicit function of $\delta$. And there are good estimates for how well the normal approximates the binomial.